# Xcode, iOS: Allocations vs real memory usage

Tags: xcode, memory, memory-management, instruments, xcode-instruments

I run my Instruments on my iPod touch 4th gen and notice that the real memory usage in the activity monitor starts from 60 MB (Introduction scene) and goes to above 100 MB (Main menu scene).

Whereas if I run the "Allocations" instrument the values in the "Allocation timeline" start from 2MB, peak to 20 MB before the Introduction scene gets loaded, and then go down to 2MB once loaded. Afterwards, once loading the main menu scene, goes up to 20 MB again and then back to 2MB.

What is the difference between those two instruments and how should I use them? In other words I thought that the memory shown in allocation was "real memory" but it seems too low.

Comment: Which instrument do you run in the first scenario?

Comment: "Activity monitor" the first time, and then "Allocations". I am using XCode 4.5